# howto build api for multiple clients

Tags: api

We are building an api for a client. We are using dependency injection for setting the business logic classes and the repository classes when calling the api method.

We have as scenario that a new client will be using our api service but they have slightly different business rule. The question I have is, what is the best way to handle the custom business logic.

I am leaning towards injecting the Custom business logic via DI based on the client (this could done by examining the api key, which is specific to client).

Thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you could use an interface as a contract for your business logic.

For example IOrder where client specific classes can inherit from:

1. DefaultOrderProcess: IOrder
2. Client1OrderProcess: IOrder
3. Client2OrderProcess: IOrder

In the container you register your interface IOrder and the specific concrete class (e.g. Client1OrderProcess) you want to use after based on your API key. From there on it is just a matter of executing the business logic as defined in the instantiated concrete class.

Comment: Thanks for your response Kay.